# Top 10 rows in oracle without using ' where ' condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to select top 10 rows in oracle without using ' where  ' condition at all ?

Comment: how do you define, these top 10 rows ? there should be an `order by` clause to definte **Top 10**. Also what version of oracle are you using ?

Comment: `fetch first 10 rows only`

Comment: I give an answer below, you can do it with 12C @goonernike you can tick as correct if you accept this answer

Comment: Prior to 12c there is no way to do it without WHERE clause. See Ersin's answer below.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a "code golf" type question, unlikely to be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

### try this:

> 10g 11g

```
select
*
from 
   (select empno, sal row_number() 
   over 
   (order by 
            sal desc) rnk from emp)
where rnk <= 10;
```

> 12c

```
select 
   ename 
from 
   emp 
order by ename 
fetch first 10 rows only;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Windows Analytic function, in this case

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2   ORDER BY col3 )

You have to indicate the columns on which "divide" the records (like GROUP BY) after PARTITION BY (no column too), and you have to specify one or more column to use for "ordering" (after ORDER BY)
Eg:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT YOURTABLE.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY xx  ORDER BY yy) AS RN
      FROM YOURTABLE) A
WHERE RN<= yourvalue
```

Eg. to extract the two highest incomes for each person in following sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TT1 ( LASTNAME VARCHAR2(50), INCOME NUMBER(12,2));
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('Stuart', 1000);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('Stuart', 2000);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('Radcliff', 3500);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('Radcliff', 4500);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('Radcliff', 6000);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES ('Stuart', 4000);

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT TT1.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LASTNAME ORDER BY INCOME DESC) AS RN
      FROM TT1) A
WHERE RN<=2;
```

Output:

```
Radcliff    6000    1
Radcliff    4500    2
Stuart      4000    1
Stuart      2000    2
```

Comment: @goonernike can you see my new example?

Answer (score 0):

> without using ' where ' condition at all

On oracle 12c just:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY somecolumn
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

On earlier versions, if you really don't want to use `WHERE` clause, 
then use `JOIN .. ON condition` instead to express a condition `first to 10 rows`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT t.*, rownum As rn
  FROM table t
  ORDER BY somecolumn
) t
JOIN dual ON t.rn <= 10
```